# Web forms, The data protection operation was unsuccessful

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a site that uses guest checkout (so they don't need to register and just place an order). To avoid certain details to be shown I have a cookie that holds some values.

I decided to encrypt the cookie data (and decrypt it when I need it, later in the process) and it as a value for `HttpCookie` (creating the cookie using this [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78c837bd.aspx)). I used ProtectData as per this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx).

Locally everything works as expected but as soon as i transfer my app to the server I get the error:

> CryptographicException: The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.

Most threads i have read seem to target MVC/Azure but my app is Web forms. I read i can make a config change but this targets Identity, so I'm unsure where i need to make a change to get this working on the server?

Comment: Are you using `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` or `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` for the `Protect` method call ? `ProtectedData` uses DPAPI which is "machine" or "user+machine" specific. You may be better off using another encryption process if you don't want it to be machine / user specific.

Comment: I am using DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser - but i can change it to LocalMachine (keeping in mind its being used for a web application for a few order details for guest users)? I know i didnt mention in the original thread but ideally i would like to use this for guest users for this site but there could be registered users too

Comment: I expect `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` to work for both guest and registered users. But, by using "LocalMachine" scope, any process running in the server can decrypt your cookie (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dataprotectionscope(v=vs.110).aspx). If this is acceptable, you can try this approach.